# Combine @Published property: get current value during update, from elsewhere

Tags: ios, swift, combine

My main problem is that I'm trying to work around the (undocumented) fact that `@Published` properties don't update the property's value until after subscribers have been notified of the change. I can't seem to get a good way around it.

**Consider the following contrived combination of a `Subject` and `@Published` properties. First, a simple class:**

```
class StringPager {
    @Published var page = 1
    @Published var string = ""
}
let pager = StringPager()
```

**And then a simple passthrough subject:**

```
let stringSubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
```

For debugging, let's subscribe to the string property and print it out:

```
pager.$string.sink { print($0) }
```

So far so good. Next, let's subscribe to the subject and alter the pager based on its value:

```
stringSubject.sink { string in
  if pager.page == 1 {
    pager.string = string
  } else {
    pager.string = string.uppercased()
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this logic will allow us to make the pager string uppercased whenever we're not on the first page.

**Now let's send values through the stringSubject when the page gets updated:**

```
pager.$page.sink { 
  $0 == 1 ? stringSubject.send("lowercase") : stringSubject.send("uppercase") 
}
```

If we've gotten this logic right, then lowercase will always be lowercased, while uppercase will always be uppercased. Unfortunately, that's not at all what happens. Here's a sample output:

```
pager.page = 1 // lowercase
pager.page = 2 // uppercase
pager.page = 3 // UPPERCASE
pager.page = 4 // UPPERCASE
pager.page = 1 // LOWERCASE
pager.page = 1 // lowercase
```

The reason for this is when we subscribe to the subject, we check the value of `pager.page`... but updating `pager.page` is what triggers the subject's closure, so the `pager.page` doesn't have an updated value yet, so the subject executes the wrong branch.

**I've tried fixing this by both `zip`ing the `pager.$page` with the subject before sinking:**

```
stringSubject.zip(pager.$page).eraseToAnyPublisher().sink { ...same code... }
```

as well as `combineLatest`ing it:

```
stringSubject.combineLatest(pager.$page).eraseToAnyPublisher().sink { ...same code... }
```

but that leads either to the exact same observed behavior (in the former case) or equally undesired behavior except more of it (in the latter case).

**How can I get the *current* page *within* the subject `sink` closure?**

Comment: Keep it simple, use $page publisher with map operator then sink it to update the value of string. Combine is not about mutation, instead transform values using Operators

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you're not actually using the power of the Combine framework. You should not be using a `sink` closure to *look* inside any value. That subverts the whole point of Combine! Instead, you should let that value *flow into* your `sink` as part of the Combine pipeline that you construct.

Let's start with your StringPager:

```
class StringPager {
    @Published var page = 1
    @Published var string = "this is a test"
}
```

And let's have a view controller class that has a StringPager, along with some test buttons that set its string or its page number:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let pager = StringPager()
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...
    }
    @IBAction func doButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let i = Int.random(in: 1...4)
        print("setting page to \(i)")
        self.pager.page = i
    }
    @IBAction func doButton2(_ sender: Any) {
        let s = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"].randomElement()!
        print("setting string to \(s)")
        self.pager.string = s
    }
}
```

You see what the idea of this test bed is. We click the first button or the second button, and we set the pager's page or string, randomly, to a new value, reporting in the console what it is.

Our goal now is create a Combine pipeline that will spit out an uppercase or a non-uppercase version of the pager's string, depending on whether the pager's page is 1 or not, every time the string or the page changes. I'll do that in `viewDidLoad`. The Combine operator that watches for any of multiple publishers to change and reports their current values when either of them changes is `combineLatest`, so that's what I'll use:

```
    pager.$page.combineLatest(pager.$string)
        .map {p,s in p > 1 ? s.uppercased() : s}
        .sink {print($0)}.store(in:&storage)
```

That's it! Now I'll tap the buttons a few times and let's see what we get:

```
this is a test
setting page to 3
THIS IS A TEST
setting page to 3
THIS IS A TEST
setting page to 1
this is a test
setting string to Jack
Jack
setting string to Manny
Manny
setting page to 1
Manny
setting page to 1
Manny
setting page to 4
MANNY
setting string to Manny
MANNY
setting string to Moe
MOE
setting string to Jack
JACK
```

As you can see, every time we change the page or the string, we get a new value out the end of the pipeline, and it is the right value! If the page is greater than 1, we get an uppercase version of the string; if the page is 1, we get the string as is. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Finally a good tiny example of leveraging Combine in a classic MVC setting outside of SwiftUI. This really is the first one I found.

Comment: @Ruiz if you don't store the `cancellable` that's returned from `sink`, it will be deallocated at some point

Comment: @halil_g I understand why the returned value from the `sink` itself would be deallocated, but are they not already stored in `page` and `string` `StringPager` values?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your intention is, I think you want to control **lowercase** & **UPPERCASE** with respect to the page number. But you are taking your logic to an extent what is not the intended job of the `Combine` framework. As one of the comments in your question by [@user1046037](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1046037/user1046037) mentions:

> `Combine` is not about mutation. Instead you should be using it for transforming your values over time.

So it should not be the `page` subscriber which triggers the value mutation of the `string` publisher. Instead you will deliberately change the value of `string`. Then you can transform the value to your desired logic bound to the `page`. And these logic should go into the object itself. Let's see what I meant:

```
class StringPager {
    @Published var page = 0
    @Published var string = "lorem ipsum"

    private var cancellableBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {

        let publisher = $page
            .map { [unowned self] in
                return $0 == 1 ? self.string.lowercased() : self.string.uppercased()
        }

        publisher
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .assign(to: \.string, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableBag) // must store the subscriber to get the events
    }
}
```

Then when you change your page value, you will get the expected cased version of the string value that the string at that time will hold.

```
let pager = StringPager()
pager.$string.sink { print($0) }
pager.page = 1 // lorem ipsum
pager.page = 2 // LOREM IPSUM
pager.page = 3 // LOREM IPSUM
pager.page = 4 // LOREM IPSUM
pager.page = 1 // lorem ipsum
pager.page = 1 // lorem ipsum
```

When you need to update your string to any value other than the previous set value, it will be independent from the page transformation. What does this mean?

```
pager.string = "new value" // new value
```

Until you deliberately set your page again:

```
pager.page = 3 // NEW VALUE
```